# How to Deserialize JSON back to objects created from db.Model

Tags: json, google-app-engine, serialization

I want to do something like this guy asked, but I want to deserialize instead of serialize.
[How to serialize db.Model objects to json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114659/how-to-serialize-db-model-objects-to-json)

Is there a library for this?  I'm running Google App Engine, and I'm getting a JSON string from appengine-rest-server (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/).

I asked the question in a different way here ([How to inspect mystery deserialized object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706208/how-to-inspect-mystery-deserialized-object-in-python)) , so I'm hoping by giving the analogy reverse of the above guy's post, it will be more clear what I'm trying to do.  If JSON doesn't work, I can use XML instead.

Comment: Have you seen [`json.load()`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) ?

Comment: Forgot URL above, but the guy said "so it uses (in Python terms) strings, numbers, lists, and dicts (four very basic data types) - and would not deserialize to my desired object.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706208/how-to-inspect-mystery-deserialized-object-in-python

Comment: Yes, familiar with json.load() but haven't seen any good/practical examples of how to serialize/deseriaize to/from existing classes.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to be able to just instantiate an instance of your desired model by passing the deserialized JSON as kwargs to the constructor. Have a look at the SDK source in `google.appengine.ext.db (__init__.py) > Model.__init__ method`

eg you could do:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

results = '{"firstname": "Neal", "lastname": "Walters"}'
data = json.loads(results)

instance = MyModel(**data)
```

This is assuming that the keys inf the dict you get back via JSON match exactly the field names, I guess they should do if the JSON is auto-generated from the models originally.

Comment: Thanks, but since the question was over a year ago, I either got around it back then or moved on to something else...

Comment: Sure, but the question lives on unanswered... :)  hopefully this is useful for people googling for similar issue.  The same idea is also possible with Django models.